# How can I cut this semi rigid aluminum duct for my dryer?

Tags: dryer

I want to cut a piece of semi rigid aluminum dryer vent duct - though in doing so I will be cutting one of the ends off that goes either into the dryer or the wall outlet for the hose - the "lip" will be missing on one end - what to do?

Answer (score 2):

If it is simple Type A vent pipe you can just cut the pipe and then use a 4" coupling that has male ends on both sides.  You should use some mastic around the male ends of the union or just simply wrap some aluminum tape around to seal the joint.

Do wear gloves when you're cutting the pipe with tin snips to prevent cuts.

Comment: the vent pipe I have already has male ends though I have to cut one off to make the vent shorter...??? please clarfiy